# Can a Patron Saint formally declared as such by a pope be replaced?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, saint, patron-saints, st-john-vianney

In the post [Can Patron Saints be "dethroned"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/60457/can-patron-saints-be-dethroned)
there seems to be some confusion between a patron saint having become no longer a patron saint, and a patron saint being "decanonized".

Here, I specifically ask:

When **a Pope declares a Saint to be a patron of something** (say, St. John Vianney who was first declared "Patron Saint of Parish Priests" by Pope Pius IX in 1929, and later made "Patron Saint of All Priests" by Pope Benedict XVI in 2010) can that Saint's office of *patron* ever be revoked by another Pope? Has it ever happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Can a Patron Saint formally declared as such by a pope be replaced?**

Generally speaking Patron Saints are rarely declared as such by Rome (Pope). When a pope decides to appoint a saint to the patronage of someone or something, he could theoretically change the patronage to another saint. However I have never ever known this to be done and doubt it will ever be done.

Fact of the matter that some professions, counties and individuals may have several patron saints for the same thing.

For example the [patron saints for fishermen](https://catholicsaints.info/patrons-of-fishermen/) are as follows:

> - Andrew the Apostle
> - Anthony of Padua
> - Benno of Meissen
> - Budoc of Brittany
> - Gundisalvus of Lagos
> - Nicholas of Myra
> - Our Lady of Mount Carmel
> - Our Lady of Salambao
> - Peter Gonzales
> - Peter the Apostle
> - Zeno of Verona

Thus Rome would simply add another Patron Saint to the list than removing one for another.

Comment: I'm curious, has a saint *ever* been removed from patronage?

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks!